# How would I factor this equation that was calculated as the determinant of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

So I have a determinant of a matrix given to be (p_0 - λ)(p_1 - λ) - (1 - p_0)(1 - p_1) which I simplified to λ^2 - λp_0 - λp_1 + p_1 + p_0 - 1
Now I need to factor this equation to determine the eigenvalues. I factored to (λ + p_1)(λ - p_0)= 1 and then λ=p_0 and λ=-p_1 Does this look correct?

Edit: 
P_0 and p_1 are constants, 
$$
det(A)=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    p_{0} - \lambda & 1 - p_{1} \\
    1 - p_{0} & p_{1} - \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Can you post the determinant please?

Comment: Added  the determinant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Determinantal equation is $\left|\begin{array}[cc] pp_0-\lambda & 1-p_0\\1-p_1 & p_1-\lambda\end{array}\right|$. If so the charactersitic polynomial will be

$(p_0-\lambda)(p_1-\lambda)-(1-p_0)(1-p_1)$

and if you foil(first-outer-inner-last) both products and collect terms in powers of $\lambda$, you get

$p_0p_1-\lambda p_0-\lambda p_1+\lambda^2-1+p_1+p_0-p_0p_1$

Notice the cancellation of the $p_0p_1$ term. This gives

$\lambda^2-(p_0+p_1)\lambda+p_0+p_1-1$

Comment: I forgot to add that p_0 and p_1 are constants and I want to solve a value for lambda in terms of p_0 and p_1.

Comment: you can use the quadratic formula to get the $\lambda$'s: $\lambda_\pm =\frac{p_0+p_1\pm\sqrt{(p_0+p_1)^2-4(p_0+p_1-1)}}{2}$

Comment: Ultimately, simplifying the argument of the square root gives: $\lambda_\pm = \frac{p_0+p_1\pm\sqrt{(p_0+p_1-2)^2}}{2} = \frac{p_0+p_1\pm (p_0+p_1-2)}{2} = \left\{1,p_0+p_1-1\right\}$

Answer (score 1):

You will get a quadratic equation in $\lambda$:
$$\lambda^2-\lambda(p_0+p_1)+p_0+p_1-1=0$$
We get $$\lambda_1=1$$ or $$\Lambda_2=p_0+p_1-1$$
so the factirzation is given by
$$(\lambda-1)(\lambda-p_0-p_1+1)$$

Comment: I forgot to add that p_0 and p_1 are constants and I want to solve a value for lambda in terms of p_0 and p_1.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the eigenvalues of this matrix without directly involving the characteristic polynomial. The original matrix is $$P=\begin{bmatrix}p_0&1-p_1\\1-p_0&p_1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Since the determinant of a matrix and its transpose are equal, a matrix and its transpose have the same eigenvalues. Observe that the sum of each of the columns of this matrix is $1$. Summing the columns is equivalent to left-multiplying by $(1,1)$, therefore $1$ is an eigenvalue of $P^T$ and hence also of $P$. (This is a general property of stochastic matrices: they always have $1$ as an eigenvalue.)

You can always find the last eigenvalue of a matrix “for free” because the trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues. Thus, we have $1+\lambda=p_0+p_1$, therefore the second eigenvalue is $p_0+p_1-1$.

With a bit more experience at this sort of thing, you might also have spotted the second eigenvalue by looking at the difference of the two columns of $P$, namely $(p_0+p_1-1,-(p_0+p_1-1))^T$. This subtraction is equivalent to right-multiplying by $(1,-1)^T$, so that’s an eigenvector of $P$ with eigenvalue $p_0+p_1-1$, just as we got from the trace, above.